# Can't subscribe to publication in Meteor

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, publish, subscribe

I have an app with a collection, publication and subscription as follows:

collections/Cities.coffee:

```
@Cities = new Meteor.SmartCollection('cities')
```

server/publications.coffee:

```
Meteor.publish "userCities", -> Cities.find { userId: @userId }
```

client/subscriptions.coffee:

```
Meteor.subscribe "cities", 
    onReady: -> console.log 'subscription a success' 
    onError: (err) -> console.log 'subscription a failure', err
```

The subscription seems to fail, the error mentions `Internal server error [500]`

There is also an error when the Meteor server starts:

```
Exception from sub DrWAY95DFAEkjBHrY TypeError: Object function (name) { ...
} has no method '_compileSelector'
```

No idea where this is going wrong. I have reset the server.

Comment: Meteor.smartCollection is retired https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-smart-collections Use regular meteor collections instead

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice I was using the Smart Collections. It's all working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Marco in the comments, Meteor.smartCollection is retired. Switching to regular collections solved the issue.